# Flex Giving user ability to change TabNavigator Labels, and send to database

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am wondering how i would enable a user to change the label on a tab navigator, eg double click the tabs and let the user rename the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/

SuperTabBar

-Nick